# Smallest $r$ for which there is an $r$-coloring of the grid wherein no two colors are adjacent more than once.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

Consider ways of coloring the $n \times n$ grid with $r$ labels so that no two labels are adjacent (horizontally or vertically) in more than one place.

Is there a good upper or lower bound on the minimum integer $r_n$ such that the $n \times n$ grid has an $r_n$-coloring?

---

### Non-example

The following grid would not be a valid $7$-coloring because (AX, AY) and (CY, BY) are both (1, 2) adjacencies:

```
A [1, 2, 7]
B [3, 2, 6]
C [4, 1, 5]
   X  Y  Z
```

### Examples

For example, on the $4 \times 4$ grid, the following $7$-coloring will work, but there are no $6$-colorings

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[3, 4, 4, 5]
[2, 6, 7, 1]
[7, 3, 5, 6]
```

Similarly, on the $5 \times 5$ grid, the following $9$-coloring will work, but there do not exist any $8$-colorings.

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
[6, 6, 7, 1, 8]
[9, 2, 7, 9, 8]
[4, 8, 5, 5, 6]
```

An example of an $8$-coloring on a $4 \times 5$ grid shows that there may be some structure to the coloring:

[image: An example of an $8$-coloring on a $4 \times 5$ grid]

```
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
 [3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
 [6, 6, 7, 5, 8]
 [2, 8, 7, 1, 8]
```

---

### Conjecture

Empirical data for the first nine terms shows that $r_n = 2n - 1$ for $n \leq 6$. and $r_n \leq 2n - 1$ for $n \leq 9$.
A stupid (?) conjecture is that $r_n = 2n - 1$.

Comment: I think I can obtain $2n-1$ as a *lower* bound, though perhaps you already have that -- so certainly the conjecture seems reasonable.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo, I don't know how to prove $2n - 1$ as any sort of bound, so I'd be interested to see what you have. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm a bit curious how you established $r_n \leq 2n-1$ for $n \leq 9$ without also establishing $r_n = 2n-1$ en passant. Was there some particular method you were using to generate these colorings other than exhaustive search? (I'd imagine an exhaustive search would have confirmed that there were no better colorings for $n \in \{7,8,9\}$).

Comment: I found a $(2n-1)$-coloring for all $n \leq 9$. The method *wasn't* an exhaustive search, so it doesn't prove anything about smaller solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about an *upper* bound, i.e., a construction of a coloring, but I think one can show fairly easily that $2n-1$ is a *lower* bound, which makes the conjecture reasonable. Assume $n > 1$, to avoid triviality. The main observation is that if the color $t$ occurs on two different squares $S_1$ and $S_2$, then if $C_1$ and $C_2$ denote the colors on squares adjacent to $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively, the sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ must be disjoint, except that possibly *one* pair of squares can have $t \in C_i \cap C_j$ (if the squares are adjacent and see each other).

Suppose we have some valid coloring with $r$ colors. For each color $t$, let $i_t$, $e_t$, and $c_t$ denote the number of occurrences of $t$ on the interior, edge, and corner squares of the grid, respectively. The observation above gives $4i_t + 3e_t + 2c_t \leq r+1$, since the color-sets arising from these squares are disjoint subsets of $\{1, \ldots, r\}$, except for the possible double-count of $t$ occuring once. Summing over all $t$ gives $4(n-2)^2 + 12(n-2) + 8 \leq r(r+1)$, since $\sum_t i_t$ is just the number of interior squares, and likewise for the other quantities. This [simplifies](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%204(n-2)%5E2%20%2B%2012(n-2)%20%2B%208) to $4n(n-1) \leq r(r+1)$.

Now for positive integers $n$ and $r$, the inequality $4n(n-1) \leq r(r+1)$ is [equivalent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%204n(n-1)%20%3C%3D%20r(r%2B1)%20for%20r) to $r \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{16n^2 - 16n + 1} - 1\right)$. Finally, whenever $n > 1$, [we have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(1%2F2)(sqrt%5B16n%5E2+-+16n+%2B+1%5D+-+1)+%3E+2n+-+2+for+n) $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{16n^2 - 16n + 1} - 1\right) > 2n-2$, so that $r > 2n-2$. As $r$ and $n$ are integers, this implies $r \geq 2n-1$.

Note, also, that the last step here [cannot be pushed further](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20(1%2F2)(sqrt%5B16n%5E2%20-%2016n%20%2B%201%5D%20-%201)%20%3E%202n%20-%201%20for%20n) to find, say, an $n$ forcing $r \geq 2n$. If such an $n$ exists, a different proof would be needed to show that $2r-1$ colors don't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Every patterns of $n*n$ grid are $S_n=2n(n-1)$, if $r_n=2n-1$, then the patterns are $T_n=_{2n-1}C_2+n=2n^2-2n+1$, this is $S_n+1$. If $r_n=2n-2$, we get $T_n=2n^2-3n+1$, this is $S_n-n+1$. Therefore assumed $r_n$ is definitely exact lower bound.